# Undefined type of nested schema for mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've build a database (using the `C#` driver) with documents :

```
{
  _id: ObjectID('xxxxxxx'),
  var: 10,
  data: {
           _id: ObjectID('yyyyyyy'),
           data_var1: 11,
           data_var2: 12
        }
}
```

I'm trying to design it with `Mongoose` as so :

```
var MyDataType = new Schema({
  _id: ObjectID,
  data_var1: Number,
  data_var2: Number
});

var schema = new Schema({
  _id: ObjectID,
  var: Number,
  data: MyDataType
});
```

However, I have this error :

> TypeError: Undefined type at `MyDataType`

Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.

From the error message, it seems that it is not possible to use schema as I do, I must either use a reference (then use the populate function of mongoose) or an array. I cannot use an array because of my database. I cannot use either a reference as the `MyDataType`has not its own collection but is an embedded document.

Is there a way to use it in with my database ?

Note: With my `C#` driver, `schema` and `MyDataType` are classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define it all in one Mongoose schema:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  _id: ObjectID,
  var: Number,
  data: {
    _id: ObjectID,
    data_var1: Number,
    data_var2: Number
  }
});
```